# What's the proper way to do back propagation in Deep Fully Connected Neural Network for binary classification

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, deep-learning, gradient-descent

I tried to implement a Deep fully connected neural network for binary classification using python and numpy and used `Gradient Descent` as optimization algorithm.

Turns out my model is heavily **under fitting**, even after **1000 epochs**. My loss never improves beyond **0.69321**, i tried checking my **weight derivatives** and instantly realized they're very small ( **as small as 1e-7** ), such small gradients are causing my model to never have **bigger gradient descent updates** and never reach the **global minima**. I will detail out the math/pseudo code for forward and backward propagation's, please let me know if I'm on the right track. I will follow the naming convention used in `DeepLearning.ai By Andrew Ng`.

Say we have **4 layer neural network** with only `one node` at the  output layer to classify between 0/1.

`X -> Z1 - > A1 - > Z2 - > A2 - > Z3 - > A3 - > Z4 - > A4`

**`Forward propagation`**

```
Z1 = W1 dot_product X + B1
A1 = tanh_activation(Z1)

Z2 = W2 dot_product A1 + B2
A2 = tanh_activation(Z2)

Z3 = W3 dot_product A2 + B3
A3 = tanh_activation(Z3)

Z4 = W4 dot_product A3 + B4
A4 = sigmoid_activation(Z4)
```

**`Backward Propagation`**

```
DA4 = -( Y / A4 + (1 - Y /  1 - A4 ) ) ( derivative of output activations or logits w.r.t to loss function )

DZ4 = DA4 * derivative_tanh(Z4) ( derivative of tanh activation, which I assume is ( 1 - (Z4 ) ^ 2 ) )
Dw4 = ( dZ4 dot_produt A3.T ) / total_number_of_samples
Db4 = np.sum(DZ4, axis = 1, keepdims = True ... ) / total_number_of_samples
DA3 = W4.T dot_product(DZ4)


DZ3 = DA3 * derivative_tanh( Z3 )
DW3 = ( DZ3 dot_product A2.T ) / total_number_of_samples
DB3 = np.sum( DZ3, .. ) / total_number_of_samples
DA2 = W3.T dot_product(DZ3)


DZ2 = DA2 * derivative_tanh( Z2 )
DW2 = ( DZ2 dot_product A1.T ) / total_number_of_samples
DB2 = np.sum( DZ2, .. ) / total_number_of_samples
DA1 = W2.T dot_product(DZ2)



DZ1 = DA1 * derivative_tanh( Z1 )
DW1 = ( DZ1 dot_product X.T ) / total_number_of_samples
DB1 = np.sum( DZ1, .. ) / total_number_of_samples
```

**This is my tanh implementation**,

```
def tanh_activation(x):
 return np.tanh(x)
```

**My tanh derivative implementation**

```
def derivative_tanh(x):
 return ( 1 - np.power(x,2))
```

After the above back propagation steps I updated the weights and biases using gradient descent with their respective derivatives. But, no matter how many times I run the algorithm, the model never improves it's loss beyond `0.69` and the derivatives of output weights ( in my case `dW4` ) is pretty low `1e-7`. I'm assuming that either my `derivative_tanh` function  or my calculations of `dZ` is really off, which is causing bad loss values to propagate back to the network. Please share your thoughts whether my implementation of backprop is valid or not. TIA. I went through 
[back propagation gradient descent calculus](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/48263/neural-network-back-propagation-gradient-descent-calculus)

and

[how to optimize weights of neural network ..](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/34171/how-to-optimize-the-weights-of-a-neural-net-when-feeding-it-with-multiple-traini) and many other blogs, but couldn't find for what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix to my problem and answered here: [What's the proper way to do back propagtion in deep fully connected neural network](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/60350/whats-the-proper-way-to-do-back-propagation-in-deep-fully-connected-neural-netw/60507#60507). I suggest closing the thread.